# Arduino servo library conflict

Tags: timer, arduino, avr

In my code I use only LiquidCrystal library and Servo library. When I try to compile the code following error appears

```
Servo/Servo.cpp.o: In function `Servo::attached()':
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/Servo/Servo.cpp:336: multiple definition of `__vector_42'
robot_v2.cpp.o:/usr/share/arduino/robot_v2.ino:662: first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/../../../avr/bin/ld: Disabling relaxation: it will not work with multiple definitions
Servo/Servo.cpp.o: In function `Servo::attached()':
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/Servo/Servo.cpp:336: multiple definition of `__vector_47'
robot_v2.cpp.o:/usr/share/arduino/robot_v2.ino:662: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Apart from above mentioned libraries, I use a 16 bit timer as follows.

```
DDRC |= B01010101;
......
cli();

TCCR4A = 0;
TCCR4B = 0;
TCCR5A = 0;
TCCR5B = 0;

OCR4A = l_target;
OCR5A = l_target;

TCCR4B = _BV(WGM42) | _BV(CS41);
TCCR5B = _BV(WGM52) | _BV(CS51);

TIMSK4 |= (1 << OCIE4A);
TIMSK5 |= (1 << OCIE5A);

sei();
```

Let me know what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this issue? Are there any other libraries than the standard Servo library for arduino? I'm using Arduino Mega board.

Here are the ISRs.

```
ISR(TIMER4_COMPA_vect)
{
   if (OCR4A != l_target) {
       OCR4A = l_target;
   }
   PORTC ^= B00000001;
}

ISR(TIMER5_COMPA_vect)
{
    if (OCR5A != r_target) {
        OCR5A = r_target; 
    }
    PORTC ^= B00010000;
}
```

Comment: I think __vector_47 reffer to ISRs, could you check that your code do not define ISRs twice? Search in place pointed by compiler. :)

Comment: @dunajski I have added the code. Please check if I'm doing anything wrong.

Comment: Does the Servo library use Timer 4 and 5? If so, what is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the related code from Servo library. According to that it uses 1,3,4 and 5 timers. So, I cannot use them for any other purpose. I will have to use Timer 2 or any other solution. I'm answering my own question as a reference for any one else who faces similar situation.

```
// Say which 16 bit timers can be used and in what order
#if defined(__AVR_ATmega1280__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__)
#define _useTimer5
#define _useTimer1
#define _useTimer3
#define _useTimer4
```

Answer (score 1):

The servo library allocates timers only as needed.  Each timer supports up to 12 servos so on the Mega, 1 to 12 servos use timer5, 13 to 24 will also use timer1 and so on. The allocation order is defined in the file ServoTimers.h as follows:  timer5, timer1, timer3, timer4

Assuming you are not using more than 24 servos, timers 3 and 4 are available. If you change all references to timer 5 (TCCR5x, OCR5x, TIMSK5) to timer 3 TCCR3x, OCR3x, TIMSK3)  you should not have the conflict.

Comment: @shan did you try to change timer5 to timer3?